# Visual Studio 2010 CxxTest: Fail build if test fails

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cxxtest

I have a solution full of C++ projects. I want to stop building and running the projects once the first project fails (aka bad exit status). In a GNU Makefile I could easily accomplish this. How do I do this in Visual Studio?

1. Run a Program as Part of Build
2. Get Exit Status
3. Fail Build if Exit Status != 0

inside of Visual Studio 2010 or higher.

Comment: In what project type?

Comment: It already works that way in the Pre- and Post-build events, no checking required.

Comment: @SLaks Its a Win32 console app.

Answer (score 0):

Digging around [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151484/fail-on-post-build-event) for a bit I came up with:

```
"$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).exe" if ERRORLEVEL > 0 goto EXIT
```

As a post build command